# Give root element new name

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Seems like I never stop banging my head with this =/
And believe me I'm not lazy because I'm asking here .:)

What I'm trying to do now is that I want to give my XML file a new root element.

So my output should be something like this.

```
<motorpark>
<fordon pris="129900"><name>Honda</name><modellTyp1/></fordon>
    <fordon pris="119000"><name>Nissan</name><modellTyp2/></fordon>
</motorpark>
```

But I cant seem to point out my template correct.

ether way It prints out my whole XML file, without even read my XSL file
Or I get  on every element thats printing out.

This is what I accomplish for the moment with some help from lwburk here on stackoverflow :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="ad">
<xsl:element name="motorpark">
<xsl:apply-templates select="autoads" mode="ad"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ad">
<xsl:element name="fordon">
<xsl:attribute name="pris">
<xsl:copy-of select="price" />
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
<xsl:element name="{concat('modellTyp', type)}">
</xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My XML file is looking like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="uppgift2.xsl"?>
<autoads>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Honda</name>
        <model>XL 1000 V</model>
        <regyear>2001</regyear>
        <price>129900</price>
        <adtext>2001 Honda XL 1000 V, 8.900 km. hög vindruta. Pris 129.900kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020115</addate>
        <volume>1000</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Nissan</name>
        <model>Almera 1.4S</model>
        <regyear>1997</regyear>
        <price>119000</price>
        <adtext>1997 Nissan Almera 1.4S, 5 dörrar, met, 70.000 km. el.spegel/fönster, galv. kaross, c.lås, startspärr, airbag, nedfällb. baks. ABS, ute temp. R/CD, alarm, d.fäste, v.säten, s/v-hj.  EU-godk. full service, servo. Pris 119.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020118</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>5 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
</autoads>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following stylesheet produces the desired result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <motorpark>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </motorpark>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ad">
        <fordon pris="{price}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
            <xsl:element name="{concat('modellTyp', type)}"/>   
        </fordon>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notice that the stylesheet's size can be greatly reduced by hardcoding element and attribute names when they're known in advance. `xsl:element` and `xsl:attribute` are usually only necessary when producing dynamic content. Also, note that you previously had two templates matching exactly the same element. We're now matching the root (`/`) and `ad` nodes separately.

Comment: You're right, I tested just with some of the code and its work, but just like you said Its more cleaner when you hardcode the elements, I will go back to some of my old tasks and rewrite them. 
Thank you again.!